# How to replace IN clause with JOIN in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have the following query.

```
select *
from table table0_
where (table0_.col1, table0_.col2, table0_.col3)
    in (($1, $2, $3), ($4, $5, $6), ($7, $8, $9), ($10, $11, $12), ($13, $14, $15))
```

How to replace IN clause with JOIN as shown in the below in the Postgres.

```
select *
from table table0_
where table0_.col1=$1
    and table0_.col2=$2
    and table0_.col3=$3
```

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328)

Comment: Ok, I will make sure to follow this in the future. Initially, I had posted in SO. Later felt that SO is mainly for programming questions and not for database-related questions. Hence, cross-posted.

Comment: Save your criteria dataset to temporary table (or use CTE) then join. Or serialize the criteria array (for example, to JSON) and parse in the query.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean:

```
select * 
from table0_ 
where (table0_.col1, table0_.col2, table0_.col3) in (($1, $2, $3) 
                                                   , ($4, $5, $6) 
                                                   , ($7, $8, $9) 
                                                   , ($10, $11, $12) 
                                                   , ($13, $14, $15))
```

Which would correspond with:

```
select * 
from table0_ 
join ( values ($1, $2, $3) 
            , ($4, $5, $6) 
            , ($7, $8, $9) 
            , ($10, $11, $12) 
            , ($13, $14, $15) ) t (col1, col2, col3)
    using (col1, col2, col3);
```

If the derived table is large you may be better off using a temporary table and inserting your parameters there

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t 
( col1 ...
, col2 ...
, col3 ... );

INSERT INTO T (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ($1, $2, $3), ...

select * 
from table0_ 
join t
    using (col1, col2, col3);
```